# What's easiest way to get filtered nodes in parameter?

Tags: xslt

I'm wondering what the easiest (and most resource friendly) way would be to transform following XML example

```
<index>
<element_1>
    <local xml:lang="en">Something in English</local>
    <local xml:lang="bg">Something in Bulgarian</local>
    <local xml:lang="cs">Something in Czech</local>
    <!-- more locales from here -->
</element_1>
<element_2>
    <local xml:lang="en">Something else in English</local>
    <local xml:lang="bg">Something else in Bulgarian</local>
    <local xml:lang="cs">Something else in Czech</local>
    <!-- more locales from here -->
</element_2>
<!-- more elements from here -->
</index>
```

Into following XML so I could store it in a parameter

```
<index>
<element_1>Something in English</element_1>
<element_2>Something else in English</element_2>
<!-- more elements from here -->
</index>
```

I know the below xslt does the trick, but since my actual files are much bigger and more complex as above example I was wondering if there are easier ways to achieve this. So using XPath instead of a template for instance. Any recommendation ?

```
<xsl:param name="indexNode" select="/index"/>
<xsl:param name="language">en</xsl:param>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$indexNode">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- index node -->
            <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                <!-- element node -->
                <xsl:copy>
                    <!-- locale node -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="local[lang($language)]"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of doing this - assuming you just want to filter out the english ones

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <index>
      <xsl:for-each select="//local[@xml:lang='en']">
         <xsl:element select="local-name(parent::*)"> //Get name of parent and create a node
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </xsl>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </index>
</xsl:template>
```